# Missing return statement java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

I have a 8x8 grid of cells, which can be either true (1) or false (0). I am trying to write a method in java which counts the number of true cells neighbouring a specified cell in column "col" and row "row". "world" is a variable describing the initial states of each cell (every bit represents a cell). getCell is a method which returns the boolean value of a cell specified by its parameters. I have tested the getCell method and it has passed all my tests, so I believe it works as intended. My code looks like this:

```
public static int countNeighbours(long world, int col, int row){
    int numNeighbours = 0;`

    if(getCell(world,col-1,row-1))
        numNeighbours++;
    if(getCell(world,col,row-1))
        numNeighbours++;
    if(getCell(world,col+1,row+1))
        numNeighbours++;
    if(getCell(world,col-1,row))
        numNeighbours++;
    if(getCell(world,col+1,row))
        numNeighbours++;
    if(getCell(world,col-1,row+1))
        numNeighbours++;
    if(getCell(world,col,row+1))
        numNeighbours++;
    if(getCell(world,col+1,row+1))

    return numNeighbours;
}
```

Esentially, it should work like this:

1. The initial number of true neighbours is 0
2. It then tests all surrounding cells, if any of them are true it increments numNeighbours by 1
3. At the end it returns the final numNeighbours

However, when I try to comply it I get an error message saying "error missing return statement". Why is it so? As far as I see, there is very clearly a return statement in the end. Could anybody please provide me som advice?

Many Thanks :)

Comment: return statement is inside last if. Try putting a semicolon after last if.

Comment: A few notes: (a) issuing curly braces would have helped here, and it's one of the reasons a lot of people (including me) like to always use them. (b) you don't have -1, -1, but you have +1, +1 twice. Was that intentional? (c) assuming wasnt, a pair of nested `for` loops would be less bug-prone here. "For colDelta from -1 to +1, for rowDelta from -1 to +1, if getCell, increment." It'd be clearer, shorter, better all around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to increment `numNeighbours` in the last condition. Therefore, your return statement was only executed if the last condition was true :

```
if(getCell(world,col+1,row+1))

return numNeighbours;
```

Change it to :

```
if(getCell(world,col+1,row+1))
    numNeighbours++; // added 

return numNeighbours;
```

Comment: Such a foolish mistake! Thank you very very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statement relates to the last `if` statement:

```
if(getCell(world,col+1,row+1)) return numNeighbours;
```

You'd better either change a body of the last `if` statement [1] or put another `return` in the end [2]:

```
// [1]
if(getCell(world,col+1,row+1)) {
    // a body
}
return numNeighbours;
...
// [2]
if(getCell(world,col+1,row+1)) {
    return numNeighbours;
}
return numNeighbours;
```

Note that I used a pair of curly braces to emphasise the statement body (it will prevent further mistakes), I'd recommend you doing so.